# Xamarin Forms Launcher

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a little project where users get match with certain events (ex: Soccer, Tennis, etc). Now I implemented a button that takes the user to a discord chat. The issue I'm having trouble figuring out is, I want each event to have its own specific button link that takes the user to the specific discord chat within the server and I'm not sure how to do that can someone help me. This is what I have so far.

```
protected async void DiscordChat_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        await Launcher.OpenAsync("https://discord.gg/nGHTS56F");
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

place the Discord ID in the `ClassId` property

```
<Button ClassId="SomeID" Clicked="DiscordChat_Tapped" ... />
<Button ClassId="SomeOtherID" Clicked="DiscordChat_Tapped" ... />
```

then in your handler

```
protected async void DiscordChat_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    var id = btn.ClassId;
   
    await Launcher.OpenAsync($"https://discord.gg/{id}");
}
```

alternately, if your `Button` is inside a template

```
protected async void DiscordChat_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    
    // cast the BindingContext to the correct type
    var item = (MyClass)btn.BindingContext;
   
    // then use some property from that type
    await Launcher.OpenAsync($"https://discord.gg/{item.SomeProperty}");
}
```